# android turn-based multiplayer custom invite screen

Tags: android, user-interface, google-play-services, multiplayer, google-play-games

I am trying to create a custom UI screen for the "player picker UI" that comes with google play services for turn based multiplayer. The default one can be seen here:
https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/realtimeMultiplayer?hl=fr-CH#invite_players_option

That page(which is real time I know) mentions how to use the default UI and that a custom UI can be used, but does not mention the actual methods to customize the look. I'm not a fan of the huge icons, and would rather a simple list. I have been trying to research this out for a few days, and have found nothing.

I am looking for any help on which methods I need to call in order to customize. Is it done in the onActivityResult method? Has anyone had any luck doing something similar?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means that you can create your own UI **from scratch**, and interact with Google Play Services using the provided API. They do not provide a way to customize the look of the player selection UI that google provides.

Comment: Oh ok. Thank you for that clarification. So I can pull the invitee list from those APIs, and display them on my own UI?

Comment: I haven't done it myself, but yes thats the general idea. I would seriously recommend against it though unless you really cant work with what they give you.